# How to find & remove duplicates in data frames?

Tags: r

I have the follwing data frame which happens to be NBA draft data:

```
 draft_year draft_round teamid playerid draft_from
 1961           1         Bos    Pol1      Nan
 2001           1         LA     Ben2      Cal
 1967           2         Min    Mac2      Nan
 2001           1         LA     Ben2      Cal
 2000           1         C      Sio1      Bud
 2000           1         C      Gio1      Bud
```

I would like to find & remove only those rows with duplicates in playerid. For obvious reasons, the remaining duplicates have a meaningful purpose and must be kept.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
## assuming df holds your data
df.unique <- df[!duplicated(df$playerid), ]
```